# Strip last part of url

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some urls looking like this:

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Ilxb2a99p6E/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuucn9e4iS4IbCmDPR7UcPlz31VlV6dw/s96-c/photo.jpg

This give a resized picture of 96x96. If "s96-c" and after is deleted then it show the original picture size.

Therefore, how do I strip the part after and including "s96-c" so it looks like this:
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Ilxb2a99p6E/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuucn9e4iS4IbCmDPR7UcPlz31VlV6dw/

Not all urls have got "photo.jpg" after the "s96-c".

So what I want to do is to look if the url contains "s96-c" and then strip that and everything after.

Thank you for your kind help!

Comment: How do the other URLs look like? I mean does all of them have s96-c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
url = url.split("s96-c")[0]
```

If "s96-c" doesn't exist, then it should return the full URL.  If it does, then it will return everything before it.

Answer (score 0):

```
url = "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Ilxb2a99p6E/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuucn9e4iS4IbCmDPR7UcPlz31VlV6dw/s96-c/photo.jpg"

print(url.split('s96-c')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect opportunity to use Regex! By using a regex expression we can split the url into 3 parts.

- The part before s96-c
- s96-c
- The part after s96-c

Here's is a code snippet

```
import re
s = "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Ilxb2a99p6E/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuucn9e4iS4IbCmDPR7UcPlz31VlV6dw/s96-c/photo.jpg"
l = re.compile("(s96-c)").split(s)
print(l)
# ['https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Ilxb2a99p6E/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuucn9e4iS4IbCmDPR7UcPlz31VlV6dw/',
#  's96-c', 
#  '/photo.jpg']
```